# PHP: Concatenate classes on each other

Tags: php, class, concatenation

How can I concatenate a class onto another class in this manner?

```
class Person { }
$p1 = new Person();
$p2 = new Person();
$p3 = $p1 . $p2;
```

Keep in mind that I will always know everything in the class that needs to be concatenated ahead of time, so generalization is not an issue.

Comment: You can't concatenate. see Design Patterns to understand how to get the correct way.

Comment: I think you want to merge the objects, but why, if they are the same objects?

Comment: I'm intrigued (and slightly disturbed) What would you actually expect your $p3 to contain? Or would it be a child class?

Comment: Brian, `var_dump($p3);`. What do I get?

Comment: @MarkBaker, @MikeB; Person would have the exact same methods but variables would be joined with each other. I know exactly what the variables are called and their types. My design requires they be concatenated, just like a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will concatenate two objects together assuming they're the same type

```
<?php

function combine_objects($obj1, $obj2) {
  if (get_class($obj1) !== get_class($obj2)) {
    throw new Exception('Class mismatch');
  }

  $className = get_class($obj1);
  $newObject = new $className;
  foreach(get_object_vars($obj1) as $key => $value) {
    $newObject->$key = $obj1->$key . $obj2->$key;
  }

  return $newObject;
}

class Person {
  public $first;
  public $last;
  public $id;
}

$john = new Person;
$john->first = 'John';
$john->last = 'Smith';
$john->id = 1;


$mary = new Person;
$mary->first = 'Mary';
$mary->last = 'York';
$mary->id = 5;

$p3 = combine_objects($john, $mary);

var_dump($p3);

/*
object(Person)#3 (3) {
  ["first"]=>
  string(8) "JohnMary"
  ["last"]=>
  string(9) "SmithYork"
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "15"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

The operation you are requesting doesn't make sense.

`.` is, in PHP, the *string* concatenation operation. A `Person` object could have a wide variety of members, some of which may not even be meaningful in string form (a reference to another object? A database handle?).

If you meant to concatenate the *string human-readable form* of a `Person` (if there is such), you can add a `__toString()` method on `Person`, and call it on `$p1` and `$p2`, putting the concatenated return value in `$p3`.

Answer (score 2):

Write a `__toString()` method for `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't allow you to overload operators (except for a few small exceptions). That being said, you can always create a workaround:

```
class Person { ... }

class People 
{ 
    // Array of Person objects
    private static $_people = Array();

    // Add person object to people object
    public function add(Array $persons)
    {
        foreach($persons as $person)
        {
           self::_people[] = $person;
        }
    }
}

$person1 = new Person;
$person2 = new Person;

$people = new People();
$people->add( Array($person1,$person2) );

...
```

Blah blah...I'm kinda ranting. This is just a concept more or less with plenty of room for improvement. My point is that you can combine objects together in a way like this.

If your goal is to literally apply the addition operator to each property in the two classes and output a junky version of the Person object, you could create a function to do that for you...it just won't be as pretty as `$person3 = $person1 + $person2;`. Instead it might look like `$person3 = add($person1,$person2);`.

Answer (score 0):

You're out of luck -- PHP doesn't let you overload operators, like C does.

Comment: C doesn't either. You probably mean C++ or C#.